# awk program to calcluate the variance of wind speed

Tags: awk, gawk

I have the below file formatted in the fashion shown below -

```
 DATA THROUGH 2001  YRS JAN FEB MAR APR MAY JUN JUL AUG SEP OCT NOV DEC ANN
BIRMINGHAM  AL  58  8.1 8.7 9.0 8.2 6.8 6.0 5.7 5.4 6.3 6.2 7.2 7.7 7.1
HUNTSVILLE  AL  34  9.1 9.4 9.8 9.2 7.9 6.9 6.1 5.8 6.7 7.3 8.1 9.0 7.9
MOBILE  AL  53  10.1    10.3    10.7    10.1    8.7 7.5 6.9 6.7 7.7 8.0 8.9 9.6 8.8
MONTGOMERY  AL  57  7.7 8.2 8.3 7.3 6.1 5.8 5.7 5.2 5.9 5.7 6.5 7.1 6.6
ANCHORAGE   AK  48  6.4 6.8 7.1 7.3 8.5 8.4 7.3 6.9 6.7 6.7 6.4 6.3 7.1
ANNETTE AK  37  11.7    11.9    10.6    10.7    9.0 8.5 7.8 8.1 8.9 11.4    11.8    12.0    10.2
BARROW  AK  68  11.9    11.3    11.3    11.5    12.0    11.5    11.7    12.4    13.2    13.3    12.4    11.7    12.0
BARTER IS.  AK  33  15.1    14.4    13.7    12.0    12.7    11.6    10.9    11.8    13.2    14.8    14.9    13.9    13.2
BETHEL  AK  43  14.5    14.8    13.8    12.9    11.5    11.0    10.7    11.0    11.6    12.3    13.2    13.7    12.6
BETTLES AK  26  5.9 6.3 7.1 7.5 7.2 6.8 6.6 6.2 6.4 6.4 5.8 5.7 6.5
```

I need to calculate the variance for every state except alaska represented by AK . 
The formula for the variance is : nƩ(x^2) -(Ʃ x^2) / n(n-1).

All I have now is some code like

```
    BEGIN {FS ="\t"} {if ($2 != "AK")
{
        sum1 = sum1 + ($4)^2
        sum2 = sum2 + $4
        n = n+1
        if($2 != "AK")
        {
                sum1 = sum1 * n;
                sum3 = sum1 - (sum2)^2
                sum3 = sum3 / (n*(n-1));
        }


}} END {}

BEGIN {FS ="\t"} {if ($2 != "AK")
{

           sum1 = sum1 * n;
           sum3 = sum1 - (sum2)^2
           sum3 = sum3 / (n*(n-1));

}}

END {print "average " sum3}
```

i get a division by zero error

I am short of ideas as to how to compute this formula . Any suggestions on breaking the code down - finding the pattersn and or complete code will be appreciated.

Comment: are the number of columns fixed or variable?

Comment: Why are you using awk for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to calculate. Can you explain it a bit better? Do you want the variance for each city over they year? Do you want the average variance of each city in a particular state over the year? Do you want the variance of each month in a particular state?

Comment: @Jay - I wante to perform a sample nalysis of variance (ANOVA) on all recorede wind speeds for the onth of june - for all states except ALASKA(AK) - - THe standard formula calculates the sum of squares of mean deviations divided by n-1 where n is the number of samples

Comment: Your code is duplicated and in the second version `n` is never incremented so it's always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sums the squares of column 10 when the state is not AK. Then uses your formula.

```
BEGIN {
    FS = "\t";
    n = 0;
}
{
    if($2 != "AK") {
        x[n] = $10 * $10;
        n++;
    }
}

END {
    sum = 0;
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
        sum += x[i];
    print (n*sum - sum) / (n * (n-1));
}
```